# Memcache installation on Solaris

Tags: php, memcached, solaris

I was trying to compile memcache with pear on solaris, but ended up with below error. I'm new to solaris could not able to figure out the issue.

```
-bash-3.2$ sudo pecl  install memcache
Password: 
downloading memcache-2.2.7.tgz ...
Starting to download memcache-2.2.7.tgz (36,459 bytes)
..........done: 36,459 bytes
11 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin /opt/csw/php5/bin/php appears to have a suffix 5/bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Enable memcache session handler support? [yes] : yes
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootPIaWpJ/memcache-2.2.7
running: /tmp/pear/temp/memcache/configure --enable-memcache-session=yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/xpg4/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /opt/csw/bin/gsed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... no
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... yes
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... yes
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.10
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.10
checking target system type... i386-pc-solaris2.10
checking for PHP prefix... /opt/csw/php5
checking for PHP includes... -I/opt/csw/php5/include/php -I/opt/csw/php5/include/php/main -I/opt/csw/php5/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/csw/php5/include/php/Zend -I/opt/csw/php5/include/php/ext -I/opt/csw/php5/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /opt/csw/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /opt/csw/php5/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking whether to enable memcache support... yes, shared
checking whether to enable memcache session handler support... yes
checking for the location of ZLIB... no
checking for the location of zlib... /usr
checking for session includes... configure: error: Cannot find php_session.h
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/memcache/configure --enable-memcache-session=yes' failed
```

Would be great if anyone can help me out of it.

Thanks,
Swaroop.

Comment: Got it resolve, Need to install php5_session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to install memcache by the same command but when it ask for session to keep in memcache, you need to say 'No' then it installs correctly.

Check if this helps you..

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Thanks Vijay, Its working. But if we want ti store session in memcache then we need to fix it by installing php5_session library.